# Do d3.js and angular.js step on each other's toes?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

Do d3.js and angular.js step on each other's toes, in the event management they employ for their internals?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. It's certainly possible to use both D3 and angular at the same time, see https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3-resources/d3-and-angular.

Comment: I think I have been hopefully specific in asking whether they would collide in their event management.

Comment: They certainly could.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff this comment isn't very specific :)

Comment: Yes. You're asking whether they could interfere, and yes, they could, e.g. if you install listeners for the same event for both. If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to provide a more specific context.

Answer (score 1):

I have used D3.js and AngularJS together. Wrapping up d3.js stuff in a custom directive worked out pretty well for me. It did create some confusion. At times, things do not work out as they are supposed to and you are left wondering why. I found this site particularly helpful:

https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3-resources/d3-and-angular

Hope this helps you in some way!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with D3.js and Angular together is the way they handle data. It is possible to use the two together by using a directive in Angular, as seen in this article:

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html.

```
angular.module('d3', [])
 .factory('d3Service', [function(){
  var d3;
  // insert d3 code here
 return d3;
}];
```